# L9 library must be installed! error occurred

Tags: vim

I tried bash shell auto-complete.

As information, I created `~/.vim/plugin` and copied `acp.vim` file.

But this message `L9 library must be installed` occurred.

How can I solve this problem? thanks.

Below is the vim version and `acp.vim`.

- vim --version : 7.4
- acp.vim

  ```
  "===========================================================================    ==
  " Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Takeshi NISHIDA
  "     
  " GetLatestVimScripts: 1879 1 :AutoInstall: AutoComplPop
  "===========================================================================    == 
  " LOAD GUARD {{{1

  try
    if !l9#guardScriptLoading(expand('<sfile>:p'), 702, 101, [])
      finish      
    endif
  catch /E117/      
    echoerr '***** L9 library must be installed! *****'
    finish
  endtry

  " }}}1 
  "===========================================================================    == 
  " FUNCTION: {{{1
  ```

Comment: Please try doing a minimal amount of research before asking for someone's time.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install the [L9 library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3252) from the same author. This is indeed hardly documented. Note that AutoComplPop isn't actively maintained any more (but it still works fine).

Comment: Additionally, the other files must be copied as well: `autoload/acp.vim` and `doc/acp.txt`.